# Problem with database when I use .env file

Tags: django, database, development-environment

When I try to migrate some changes on one of the models I get this error but only when I use `.env` file in `settings.py`:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

My `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ.get('DB_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```

My `.env` file

```
# DB
DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
DB_NAME=db
DB_USER=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
```

My Pycharm `.env` settings [image]

When I set up my `settings.py` back to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I don't have any problems to migrate.

Comment: How are you running the migration then…?

Comment: @deceze I set up my database in settings.py back to 
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate and it's all good but when I switch to .env file in settings it gives an error.

Comment: You do notice that you've configured your .env file specifically for the task of running the server in PyCharm? If you execute the migration via any other mechanism, the .env file isn't getting loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the `.env` file inside your settings, not PyCharm.

One way to do this is to use [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Here's how you would use it in your `settings.py`:

```py
import environ
import os

env = environ.Env()

# Set the project base directory
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

# Load the environment variables
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': env('DB_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': env('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': env('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```

Be sure to [install the package](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) first.

Check out the [quick start](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#quick-start) or [this Medium article](https://alicecampkin.medium.com/how-to-set-up-environment-variables-in-django-f3c4db78c55f) for more examples.