Unable to update latest database configuration in settings.py in django
I write code on my local machine and then use github to transfer the code to my Amazon AWS EC2 server, I am using AWS Route53 to connect to a domain name and AWS RDS for database (started using recently, few days ago).
In my previous code I was using Hostinger's remote mysql capability for a hosted database which was working fine, I deployed the code on AWS EC2 server and tested, however, when I created MySql database using RDS and updated its details in the settings.py the application is still being run using the old Hostinger's database settings only.
I have tried the following things:

deleting all the cache files,
removing all migrations files and creating migrations once again,
checked settings.py (database configuration settings) multiple times
Restarted the EC2 instance, restarted supervisor, gunicorn, nginx
Deleted the RDS database and created one more and updated its respective settings in settings.py

To my surprise, for some reason it is still working on the old database, I am not able to figure out where exactly is it picking up the details of the old database and why is the latest settings.py file not being loaded in real time?

is there multiple settings.py file can you confirm that in your local?? and please also check if you have setup any varaibles in github pipelines

there is only one settings.py file in my local as well as on EC2 server. Secondly, there are no environment variables being used to point to settings.py

can you sahre your settings.py after redacting the credentials

Please let me know if the following file is accessible to you:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dxGJvIEeO7dQj9FLGalTi6KMn8eIWRDQ/view?usp=sharing

Can you check your manage.py file and check for a line like this
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.settings')
YOUR_PROJECT_NAME should be correct here.
Then run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 instead of gunicorn and see if its taking the right settings.py

can you run the django shell using python manage.py shell  and enter this from django.conf import settings
print(settings.DATABASES) and show us the output in the ec2, redact the cred and send the image

@ArunT the following line is present in manage.py and when i run the development server on 0.0.0.0:8000 it is still running with old db configuration...

@nabinsademba I tried what you said, interestingly, it is printing the old database configuration details...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cWtrzWETS7aS_rNQRZ9T6rWSfDjDethQ/view?usp=sharing

printenv | grep -i 'DATABASE' & printenv | grep -i 'DJANGO_'
run this in you shell and send the output again

The above commands are giving error in python3 manage.py shell, so with the help of ChatGPT I created a script doing the same task, the script and its output is shared below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18rtsOwyxUjJM7q9UGAGXMIVVmtVn3Baf/view?usp=sharing
Only one variable was returned, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=priceactionrepository.settings

if i could access your ec2 and repo i could have resolved much faster but try setting the db  using .env  file , i think there are plenty of resources how to setup db with .env file in django  or you can reference this stackoverflow thread:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75107730/problem-with-database-when-i-use-env-file

During an earlier git pull, the settings.py file was inadvertently pulled from project_name/project_name/settings.py to project_name/settings.py. This resulted in multiple copies of the file, and I mistakenly made edits to the latter one, which did not affect the original settings file.
I have since amended the correct settings.py file, and the changes are now properly reflected.
Thank you, @nabinsademba and @ArunT, for your assistance. I appreciate your time and apologize for any inconvenience caused.
The issue has been resolved. Thank you once again!
